# Change e-mail address PHP contact form

Tags: php, forms, email-headers

I am currently working on my contact form script and everytime when I fill in my contact form I am receiving the mail perfectly with no problems at all. The e-mail looks like this

From: noreply@domain.tld and subject: Contact Form Submission. I would like to change noreply@domain.tld into My company name... so that everytime when I'm receiving the mail that I won't see the email address displaying but instead of that I will see my company name. Ofcourse, reply-to function has to stay active. Can someone help me out?

```
    <?php

// Check if the form has been posted
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    // The email address the email will be sent to
    $to = "xx@domain.pl";
    // The email subject
    $subject = "Contact Form Submission";
    // Set the from and reply-to address for the email
    $headers = "From: no-reply@xxx.pl\r\n"
             . "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion();
    // Build the body of the email
    $mailbody = "The contact form has been filled out.\n\n"
              . "Name: " . $_POST['naam'] . "\n"
              . "Email: " . $_POST['email'] . "\n"
              . "Message:\n" . $_POST['vraag'];
    // Send the email
    mail($to, $subject, $mailbody, $headers);
    // Go to the thank you page
    header("location: thankyou.html");
    exit;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format of the e-mail adress should comply with the [RFC 2822](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2822.html) standard:

> Normally, a mailbox is comprised of two parts: (1)    an optional
>   display name that indicates the name of the recipient    (which could
>   be a person or a system) that could be displayed to the    user of a
>   mail application, and (2) an addr-spec address enclosed in    angle
>   brackets ("<" and ">").  There is also an alternate simple form    of
>   a mailbox where the addr-spec address appears alone, without the recipient's name or the angle brackets.

So, you should write like `"Company name <name@company.tld>"`. Replace this line:

```
$headers = "From: no-reply@domain.tld\r\n"
```

with:

```
$headers = "From: Company name <no-reply@domain.tld> \r\n"
```